# Differentiability of a function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega$ be an open convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $L:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a linear functional and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R^m$ be differentiable with $f'(\mathbf X)=$ $L$ for all $\mathbf X \in$ $\Omega$. Show that there exists $\mathbf v \in$ $\mathbb R^m$ such that $f(\mathbf X)=L(\mathbf X)$ + $\mathbf v$ for all $\mathbf X\in$ $\Omega$.

Since $f$ is differentiable, the error function $\epsilon (H)=$ $\frac {f(X+H) - f(X) - L(H)}{\lVert H \rVert}$ $\to$ $0$ as $\lVert H \rVert$ $\to$ $0$. From here, we have, $f(X+H)=$ $f(X)+L(H)$. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mean value theorem. Fix $x_0\in\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is convex, the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ is contained in $\Omega$. Then
$$
f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(\xi)(x-x_0)=L(x-x_0).
$$

Comment: Wow! It's an elegant solution. Thanks a lot. Can you refer a nice theory/problem book on this topic i.e. Functions of several variable? I am struggling a bit with this right now.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables). It is an easy consequence of the one dimensional result.